# Print table - Bootstrap-vue

Tags: bootstrap-vue

How can I print a table in bootstra-vue, so that the user can print it by clicking a button?

*print the entire table on a paper print*

```
<b-table id="my-table" hover striped small outlined :items="valuesData" :fields="fields" class="mt-0 mb-0">
</b-table>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? What do you mean by print? Are you looking to load data to the table on a click?

Comment: @tbowden Sorry, I need to print the entire table on a paper print.

Comment: If you just want to print the table only, you will need other styling to hide the rest of the page, just like with plain `<table>` elements. Or open a new window with just our `<b-table>` component that people can then print.

Comment: @Troy Morehouse How can I make the first option to print? In some cases I see that a screen suitable for printing is opened, just as it is when a pdf file is opened.

Comment: `<b-button @click="window.print()">Print</b-button>`

Comment: @TroyMorehouse Two errors will occur

1 - Property or method "window" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
2 - Cannot read property 'print' of undefined

Comment: You may need to make a method (ie. `doPrint()`) to call `window.print()`, and then `@click="doPrint()"` so that `window` is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @TroyMorehouse Ok, but it is printing the entire page, I would like to print only the table.

Comment: You will need to either dynamically add class `d-print-none` on elements that you don't want printed, or use custom CSS to change the display property on elements you don't want printed.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/display/#display-in-print. The other option is to create a dedicated page (or use a query string param) that has the table only that the user can print.